# Creating an exception without conditions?

Tags: java, exception

I have to create a program in which I input 2 values simultaneously but, these values must range from 50 to 127. If the value is less than 50 or above 127 it should show an exception saying "value entered" is too low or too high. As a requirement for the program, I cannot use flow-control statements. I have not tried anything as I am lost
UPDATE: WITH THE HELP OF YOUR COMMENTS I HAVE SATISFIED THE 127 CONDITION, AND MAY BE ON THE WAY TO SATISFYING THE LOWER CONDITION WITH THE NEXT(PATTERN) METHOD. I AM CURRENTLY CONTACTING MY TEACHER AND ASKING IF SATISFYING THE 127 CONDITION IS ENOUGH. THANK YOU ALL

UPDATE 2: the 127 condition was enough!

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class A1_Q1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // declaration of variables
        double x, y, z;
        int p, q;
        Scanner kBoard = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Welcome to the Simple 3D-Space Program:");
        System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
        System.out.print("Enter values for 'p' and 'q' simultaneously. Must be between 50 and 127:");

        String input = kBoard.nextLine();

//separating first number and second number from the inputed line
        String firstNum = input.substring(0, input.indexOf(" "));
        String secondNum = input.substring(input.indexOf(" "), input.length());

//isolating numbers from the strings and filtering out
        String numOnlyP = firstNum.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");
        String numOnlyQ = secondNum.replaceAll("[^0-9]", "");

//transforming string into integer values
        p = Integer.parseInt(numOnlyP);
        q = Integer.parseInt(numOnlyQ);

//to check and see if previous code was functioning correctly
        System.out.println(p + " " + q);
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain what your specific problem is?

Comment: I have to create a program in which I input 2 values simultaneously but, these values must range from 50 to 127. If the value is less than 50 or above 127 it should show an exception saying "value entered" is too low or too high. As a requirement for the program, I cannot use flow-control statements.

Comment: Please edit your question and include what you've already tried (code).

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "I cannot use flow-control statements"?  The statement seems clear enough, but it is a very surprising constraint on its face, so I'm wondering whether there has been some miscommunication there, either between your instructor and you or between you and us.

Comment: A note my instructer added to the assignment and a step was NOTE 2:
(i) Do not use any other library/package other than java.util.Scanner
(ii) Do not use any flow-control statements such as selection (if-else), iteration (loops), etc.
  Kindly note that if you enter values beyond 127 for either user inputs p and q,
respectively; your program will run into an Exception.

Comment: Ok. Then is the part about throwing an exception for inputs that are too small your own invention?  And the specific exception message you give in the question, is that your own invention?

Comment: So what is your actual problem then?  Do you not know what an exception is or how they work?  Do you not know how to declare an exception class?  Do you not know how to throw an exception?  Do you know how to catch / handle an exception?   If you are "totally lost" ... I suggest looking for a map; i.e. a tutorial on exceptions such as this one: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/index.html

Comment: I would advise asking your teachers what they meant by the no "flow control statements" requirement.  Ask them do they really mean that `if (some condition) { throw new SomeException(...); }` is not allowed?   Personally ... I suspect that they have "mispoken",

Comment: I am emailing my teacher today and shall hopefully come back with clarification. I have not yet learned about throw and catch in my course so I am assuming that It is not expected of me to use a custom exception.

Answer (score 0):

The constraint against using flow control statements is highly artificial, but it does force you into a certain direction.  For the program to behave differently for some inputs than it does for others *requires* flow control.  If you cannot use flow control in your program then that means the needed flow control must be somewhere else.  And the only "somewhere else" you are allowed to use is `java.util.Scanner`.

As a blooming programmer, some of the things you need to learn and have ready at all times at the tip of your brain are the powers of two, and certain ones of them especially.  Among those is 2<sup>7</sup> = 128, which has special significance as one more than 127, the maximum value of an 8-bit two's complement integer, such as a Java `byte` (these properties are closely related).  And lo and behold, the maximum value your program is supposed to accept is 127.

Read the API docs of `Scanner`, especially those for scanning inputs of various specific Java types.  You will find some that can serve the purpose of (as a side effect) throwing an exception for inputs larger than 127. If you want to throw a custom exception instead, then you can catch the one thrown by the `Scanner` and throw one of your choice in its place -- provided that `try` / `catch` is not considered flow control.

`Scanner` could be pressed into service for an exception for violation of the lower bound, too, but that would require a very unnatural hack.

Details are left as the exercise they are intended to be.

Comment: I get that _your_ brain pinged straight to: Oh, hey... 127 - we could read a byte! - but the exercise also includes _50_ as a lower bound, so that thought is irrelevant here. 'just read a byte' cannot deliver on the requirement. Only half of it, with absolutely no way to go from there to 'all of it', and thus, this answer is probably not salvagable.

Comment: @rzwitserloot, the OP is inconsistent between question and comments as to whether there is in fact a requirement to throw an exception on low inputs at all.  However, if indeed there is one then `Scanner` can indeed be (mis)used to produce it, as this answer already says. And that's the only option available to the OP anyway.  There may be a bit more room available to hint without outright doing the OP's homework problem for them, but I prefer to err on the side of letting the student stretch themselves.

Comment: The problem I have with this answer is that it missed both targets. If the aim is to lead the horse to water so to speak, then it did a bad job, misleading by talking about 127 being special, which is irrelevant for finding the actual hack (and I'd say using such a limit to get an exception on the 127 bound is just as much of an unnatural hack, given that the lower bound is 50, thus, likely a mere coincidence). Instead, just link to the scanner javadoc and indicate that the answer is buried inside, so look _real_ close at _every_ method available.

Comment: If instead the aim of the answer is to answer the question head-on, it should just do so, and not beat around the bush with this almost-but-in-the-end-useless-distraction territory of `nextByte`. Just mention `next(Pattern)`. At any rate, given that such an answer would require a near total rewrite I've put in the effort.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a tad disingenuous. A requirement that 50-127 is accepted, the rest is not, is not normally possible without flow control. So we *need* flow control, but, we're not allowed to use flow control.

Quite the dilemma.

It's a bit like an escape room. You must screw together this intricate thing, but, you don't have a screwdriver (all your pockets were emptied before entering it), so now what? Well, you look around the room. What tools *do* you have? Even if they are epically not suited to the job, can they be used to deliver?

So, let's look. What do we have? We have scanner.

We need to look at [what you can do with those](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html), and see if that helps, because other than Scanner you're not given much room to work.

And lo! Scanner delivers. It's a method that is almost never used with scanner, but it's there, and it'll give us a way through: [The `next(Pattern)` method](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#next(java.util.regex.Pattern)) can do the job.

Quoting from the javadoc:

> Returns the next token if it matches the specified pattern.

Great!

Now, I'm flabbergasted, but **the docs are broken**. Java is used by millions of people and the docs are taken fairly seriously, so that is mostly an indictment on how little this method is used. Nobody, apparently, noticed. The thing missing from the docs is subtle, but important: What happens if the next token in the stream *does not* match the specified pattern? The docs don't say. But the scanner acts the exact same way as when you call e.g. `nextInt()` and the next token is *not* an int: It throws `InputMismatchException`.

This means `next(Pattern)` is the complete package: Will pass if input 'matches the pattern' and throws if it does not, so now all we need is a pattern that matches if the input is 50-127 and fails otherwise. We can trivially do that, though we'll need to dive into [Regular Expressions](https://www.baeldung.com/regular-expressions-java) to do the job - as that is the 'language' for the pattern we can provide to this next method. (There is a `String` variant too, but it just parses your string as... a regular expression, so we can't get out of reading up on those).

```
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int value = s.next("[5-9][0-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-7]");
```

It's a rather unwieldy pattern, but it'll get the job done. This pattern says:

- The input has to be one of these 3 different options (`a|b|c` is regexp for: either `a`, or `b`, or `c`)
- Option 1: A 5/6/7/8/9, followed by any digit.
- Option 2: A 1, followed by a 0 or a 1, followed by any digit.
- Option 3: A 1, a 2, and then a 0/1/2/3/4/5/6/7.

That'll covers 50-127. If you want e.g. `00050` to be okay too, stick a `0*` on the front, which regexp for 'any amount of zeroes'.

I think this exercise is quite a reach. As the answers provided so far clearly attest, no java programmer would get in their right mind to solve such a task by using the regexp pattern powers of scanner, they'd just read an `int` and use an `if` like normal. As the unwieldiness of that regexp shows, using a regex pattern to limit numeric input is not really what it is meant for. A key insight into writing readable, flexible code is to avoid doing that: Using a thing in a way that the author of the thing clearly was not at all thinking about when they wrote it is a fine way to create confusing code that runs into bugs quickly and may no longer work nearly as well in future updates of said thing. I guess it's testing if you can think creatively and read documentation, perhaps?

If you can contact the author of this question, you might want to have them read this answer too :)

I'll be filing a bug over at OpenJDK about the subtle mistake in the docs, at any rate.

Comment: This bug [has already been filed](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8059011) in 2014 and has so far been completely ignored for 9 years. Bizarre.

Comment: would there be a way to input 2 values between 50 - 127 with this method?

Comment: Of course. Just call `.next(thatPattern)` twice.

Answer (score 0):

Quite standard approach for such problems is to use lookup tables, something like this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TestProgram {
    private interface Handler {
        void handle(final int value);
    }
    private static class NullHandler implements Handler {
        public void handle(final int value) { }
    }
    private static class TooLowHandler implements Handler {
        public void handle(final int value) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value " + value + " is too low");
        }
    }
    private static class TooHighHandler implements Handler {
        public void handle(final int value) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Value " + value + " is too high");
        }
    }
    private static void checkLow(final int value) {
        final int sign = ((value - 50) >> 31) & 1;
        new Handler[]{new NullHandler(), new TooLowHandler()}[sign].handle(value);
    }
    private static void checkHigh(final int value) {
        final int sign = ((value - 128) >> 31) & 1;
        new Handler[]{new TooHighHandler(), new NullHandler()}[sign].handle(value);
    }
    public static void main(final String args[]) {
        final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        final int p = scanner.nextInt();
        final int q = scanner.nextInt();
        System.out.println(p + " " + q);

        checkLow(p); checkLow(q);
        checkHigh(p); checkHigh(q);
    }
}
```